# Python dictionary magic needed

Tags: python, dictionary, flask, jinja2

I have these two Python dictionaries with a location and a quantity associated.

```
A: {'Pompano Beach': ['13'], ' Miami': ['18'], ' W. Palm Beach': ['18']}
B:  {'Atlanta': ['25'], 'Las Vegas': ['50+']}
```

I need to print them out in an html table. I am currently using flask with jinja2 templating.

I would like to have my results as:

```
C: {'Pompano Beach': ['13', '0'], ' Miami': ['18', '0'], ' W. Palm Beach': ['18', '0'], 'Atlanta': ['0','25'], 'Las Vegas': ['0', '50+']}
```

Where the 0 index in each list value is that of A's quantity and the 1 index is that of B's quantity.
Also, where if the city doesn't exist in B then add a 0. Same for if it does not exist in A then add a 0 in its corresponding index.

I'm not sure if there's an easier solution but I have come to the point where I believe this is what I need in order to keep my styling with jinja2 templating.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a dict comprehension while using `.get` with default value of `['0']`:

```
C = {k: A.get(k, ['0']) + B.get(k, ['0']) for k in list(A) + list(B)}
print(C)
```

outputs

```
{'Pompano Beach': ['13', '0'], ' Miami': ['18', '0'], ' W. Palm Beach': ['18', '0'], 
 'Atlanta': ['0', '25'], 'Las Vegas': ['0', '50+']}
```

You can get the same output while avoiding the creation of the 2 extra lists with

```
C = {k: A.get(k, ['0']) + B.get(k, ['0']) for k in A.keys() | B.keys()}
```